# Issue while doing sed operation

Tags: shell

I have a string containing a string like

```
"landing_page_url":"$landingPage",
```

I am trying to replace it with something like

```
landingURL="https://www.landingpage.com/?utm_source=paypal&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=rtg-cash-15for250"
```

I am trying to replace the above mentioned string using the command

```
request_body=$(echo $request_body | sed 's~"landing_page_url":.*$~"landing_page_url":"'"${landingURL}"'",~' )
echo $request_body
```

I am getting

```
 "landing_page_url":"https://www.landingpage.com/?utm_source=paypal"landing_page_url":"$landingPage",utm_medium=cpc"landing_page_url":"$landingPage",utm_campaign=rtg-cash-15for250",
```

instead of

```
"landing_page_url" : "https://www.landingpage.com/?utm_source=paypal&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=rtg-cash-15for250"
```

please help with the issue ?

Comment: what is $request_body content? Where are you trying to replace the content? Is it in a text file/html file or any other file?

Comment: You should use JSON aware tools like `jq` to work with JSON data, not `sed` or other string-oriented things.

Comment: I am using Json, I cannot install any tools like jq.